# Php file_put_contents json into csv single cell

Tags: php, json, csv

```
file_put_contents(
            $log,
            $this->info['http_code'].", ".
            $this->info['url'].", ".
            '{"12345":"98765","56789":"54321"}'.", ".
            date("Y-m-d H:m:i") .", ".
            PHP_EOL,
            FILE_APPEND
        );
```

I have a log required to save `json` into one `single csv cell`

Because comma (,) it jump to next column's cell.

Anyone know how to store this json data in single cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Here instead of using `file_put_contents` you should use `fputcsv` add also there is no need for `PHP_EOL`, in this current string next time you call `fputcsv` then it will automatically comes into your next line.

```
<?php
$resource=fopen($log, "w+");
fputcsv($resource, 
   array(
      $this->info['http_code'],
      $this->info['url'],
      '{"12345":"98765","56789":"54321"}',
      date("Y-m-d H:m:i")
    )
);
```

Comment: sry i actually only want json part in single column

Comment: @BenjaminW Do you want json to be inserted like cells?

Comment: all json in single cell,

Comment: Try this, it will put you json in one cell.

Comment: just make sure you are using `.csv` extension for your `$log` and also put only array of strings as a second argument in `fputcsv`